# IPTABLES CODE ISSUE

Tags: iptables, dns

I am using iptables to block all the ports. However to allow ping www.google.com I am using the following code

```
filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 53  -j ACCEPT
filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

This works fine though saving it gives me error because using the filter in start is not the right way. However when I use the code without word filter the ping to www.google.com doesn't work. PS I am directly saving to iptables files under /etc/sysconfig

Edit: Ok it seems the filter broke the whole code and iptables was deleting the whole rules. The problem is that I can't ping www.google.com despite opening my DNS port.

Comment: is it ping or DNS?

Answer (score 2):

The `ping` utility uses [ICMP (Internet Message Control Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol), not [UDP (User Datagram Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) or [TCP (Transmission Control Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol). To allow outgoing `ping` requests through your fire-wall you could add a rule such as the following:

```bsh
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ALLOW
```

You probably also want to add a rule such as the following to allow the returning traffic:

```bsh
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I have already added these rules. -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT                The problem is with resolution of dns. I want to ping it because I want to use yum and other service which can not resolve the urls

Comment: @user2976690 Can you update your question to include your full iptables rules and also the command that you're executing using along with any error messages that it generates?

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of iptables rules is important: the *first* matching rule with either `-j ACCEPT`, `-j DROP` or `-j REJECT` will decide the fate of the packet. Adding new rules after a "drop everything" rule will have no effect, as the matching packets would never reach that rule.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the correct rules were these . Got it from a forum issue resolved.

```
-A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```